# Max Flow & Min Cut. Did I get it right?

Tags: algorithm

[image]

Did I get the max flow for this configuration?
Since Min cut value == 20 == Flow value
Is it safe to assume that I've got it?

Comment: Is it a programming question ?

Comment: It's an algorithm questions where I have to get the max flow out of given graph. btw, thanks for putting the image up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's right. I hope these will convince you.

1) The flow of a graph will always not larger than any cut of the graph. Since, the flow is equal to the cut, it will be the max-flow.

2)You will never find any augmenting path any more. Since all forward edges from S are full. It also shows it is the max-flow.

Comment: Great way to double check. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it looks right. The max flow problem is equivalent to the min cut problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's right.

We may find that the max-flow problem and the min-cut are equivalent. 
Some solutions are introduced [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem#Solutions). And the Ford–Fulkerson algorithm is a classic solution for this problem.

**The key insight of this algorithm is to search an augmenting path (a path with available capacity) repeatedly, and to gain flow to that path, until there is no such augmenting path.**

In addition, DFS or BFS can be used in finding such path.